# Multi-level hierarchical data sorting C#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have an entity:

```
public class Document
{
    public int id;
    public int? ParentId;
    public string name;
}
```

And data in database:

```
id  |  ParentId | name
-----------------------
1   |           |  fruits
2   |           |  vegetables
3   |     2     |  tomatoes
4   |     1     |  apples 
5   |     4     |  golden apples
6   |     4     |  red apples
```

Or, as C#:

```
var documents = new[]
{
    new Document() { id = 1, ParentId = null, name = "fruits" },
    new Document() { id = 2, ParentId = null, name = "vegetables" },
    new Document() { id = 3, ParentId = 2, name = "tomatoes" },
    new Document() { id = 4, ParentId = 1, name = "apples" },
    new Document() { id = 5, ParentId = 4, name = "golden apples" },
    new Document() { id = 6, ParentId = 4, name = "red apples" },
};
```

I need to get:

```
id  |  ParentId | name
-----------------------
1   |           |  fruits
4   |     1     |  apples
5   |     4     |  golden apples
6   |     4     |  red apples
2   |           |  vegetables
3   |     2     |  tomatoes
```

How I can quick sort hierarchical data in c#?

Comment: sort by which column?

Comment: Your class `Document` cannot represent the data you've provided. `ParentId` must either be `int?` or your data must have a value for every row. Please provide your input data as valid C# code.

Comment: Oh, and your class def is not valid C#. You should make the effort to make it as easy for us to answer as possible.

Comment: None of the columns in the "I need to get" are sorted.

Comment: @NightOwl888 - He want's to do a depth first ordering - it's not a single sort by a column.

Comment: @ruslanen *Why* do you want to do that in C#? Most databases provide ways to perform hierarchical queries. SQL Server even provides the `hierarchyid` to allow you to specify and index hierarchies

Comment: @NightOwl888 seems to be a sorted tree: OrderBy(parentId).ThenBy(id), just resolving the hierarchies. Calls for recursive extension method. anyone? ;)

Comment: asdf_enel_hak, sort by id 
and with the order of opening nodes

Comment: @ruslanen you could actually "steal" SQL Server's techinque: A `hierarchyid` is essentially the path along the hierarchy, eg `ID1/ID21/ID211` Sorting/Querying this is the same as sorting/querying any other value.

Comment: Well, you just need to sort by node without parent if you add nodes from up to leafs if you don't support their relational modification. That's all, really. No need to overcode. All identifiers already sorted in right direction, except root one.

Comment: @ruslanen - And my edit shows what you should have posted to begin with.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, given:

```
public class Document
{
    public int id;
    public int? ParentId;
    public string name;
}
```

And:

```
var documents = new[]
{
    new Document() { id = 1, ParentId = null, name = "fruits" },
    new Document() { id = 2, ParentId = null, name = "vegetables" },
    new Document() { id = 3, ParentId = 2, name = "tomatoes" },
    new Document() { id = 4, ParentId = 1, name = "apples" },
    new Document() { id = 5, ParentId = 4, name = "golden apples" },
    new Document() { id = 6, ParentId = 4, name = "red apples" },
};
```

Then this works:

```
var lookup = documents.ToLookup(x => x.ParentId);

Func<int?, IEnumerable<Document>> heirarchySort = null;
heirarchySort = pid =>
    lookup[pid].SelectMany(x => new[] { x }.Concat(heirarchySort(x.id)));

IEnumerable<Document> sorted = heirarchySort(null);
```

It gives you:

[image: Sorted Documents]

---

Local functions now make this a little nicer on the eye.

```
IEnumerable<Document> heirarchySort(int? pid) =>
    lookup[pid].SelectMany(x => new[] { x }.Concat(heirarchySort(x.id)));
```